# Disable focus for tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, focus

How can I make a widget that will not get the focus ever in tkinter?
For example, a button that when I will press TAB the focus will skip on him

Comment: Please provide some sample code, or try to explain further your issue and point out exactly where and when it went wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found some time to provide a working example:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

but1 = tkinter.Button(root, text ="Button 1")
but1.pack()

butNoFocus = tkinter.Button(root, text ="Button no focus", takefocus = 0)
butNoFocus.pack()

but2 = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button 2")
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The `takefocus` option set to `0` will disable tab focus on `butNoFocus`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old question, but for any future readers, a simpler way to remove cycling focus for widgets is by unbinding `<<NextWindow>>`, as stated by Bryan Oakley here in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494540/using-python-3-7-3-how-do-i-disable-tkinters-background-tab-key-binding).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Hello')  # Two example buttons
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='World!')

button1.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=10)
button2.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10)

root.unbind_all('<<NextWindow>>')  # Unbinding the behavior that causes Tab Cycling
root.mainloop()
```

This will disable Cycling all widgets with Tab, if you would want to remove cycling focus for a single widget, setting `-takefocus` to 0 would be easier