# Using Python 3.7.3, how do I disable Tkinter's background "Tab" key binding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, focus, bind, setfocus

I'm trying to intercept the Tab character press without explicitly binding to it at the root or frame level, as this would increase complexity more than desired. 
I really don't want to bind a simple handler to every button.

I want to know two things:

1. How do I intercept/disable the background "Tab" key binding?
2. The Space Bar triggers the command associated with that button after tabbed (even if you manually call widget.focus_set() on a different widget that the current tabbed one): how do I prevent this?

For some reason, Tkinter processes the Tab key to advance to the next object automatically. I don't want this in my case. I also tried "return 'break'" based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062172/9530917) but it doesn't seem to work, or the "_get_key" event handler occurs after the background binding.

```
class testFocus:
    btns = { }
    string = ''
    NumberCharList = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'period', 'comma', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.top = root
        self.top.bind('<Key>', self._get_key)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.var = tk.StringVar(value='Type: ')
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.var)
        self.lbl.pack()

        for i in range(15):
            self.btns[i] = tk.Button(self.frame, text=f'Click {i}', command=lambda x=i: print(x))
            self.btns[i].pack()

    def _get_key(self, event):
        print('Root._get_key.event.keysym: ', event.keysym)
        print(root.focus_get())
        if event.keysym in self.NumberCharList:
            self.string += event.keysym
            self.var.set(self.string)
        elif event.keysym == 'Tab':
            print('TAB!') # NOT WORKING...WHY?
        elif event.keysym == 'Delete':
            self.string = ''
            self.var.set(self.string)
        elif event.keysym == 'BackSpace':
            self.string = self.string[:-1]
            self.var.set(self.string)
        # ... other code that handles specific key presses.
        print(root.focus_get())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry(f"800x480+{int(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 8)}+{int(root.winfo_screenheight() / 6)}")
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)
    root.title('Tests')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app = testFocus(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Tab Output:

```
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.
.
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button
.!frame.!button
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button2
.!frame.!button2
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button3
.!frame.!button3
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button7
.!frame.!button7
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button8
.!frame.!button8
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button9
.!frame.!button9
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button10
.!frame.!button10
Root._get_key.event.keysym:  Tab
.!frame.!button12
.!frame.!button12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I intercept/disable the background "Tab" key binding?

The default tab behavior is based on a binding to the `"all"` binding tag. You can remove that binding to remove the default tab behavior.

```
root.unbind_all("<Tab>")
```

Depending on the underlying version of tk your python is using, it might be using a binding to `<<NextWindow>>` rather than directly on the tab key. In that case you need to unbind the virtual event `<<NextWindow>>` in a similar way:

```
root.unbind_all("<<NextWindow>>")
```

If you're wanting to remove the behavior tabbing to the next window, you're probably going to want to remove it for the previous window too. That binding is for the virtual event `<<PrevWindow>>`

```
root.unbind_all("<<PrevWindow>>")
```

> The Space Bar triggers the command associated with that button after tabbed (even if you manually call widget.focus_set() on a different widget that the current tabbed one): how do I prevent this?

That absolutely will not happen. The space key can only trigger a button if it has focus, or you've explicitly set your own binding to handle the space key in other widgets.

Comment: @Jakar510: "didn't work" is uselessly vague. I can say with 100% confidence that using `unbind` in this way absolutely will prevent the tab key from moving focus. It won't prevent the tab from triggering your binding on `<Key>`, because tkinter still sees the tab key being pressed, but it definitely won't change the focus.

Comment: after using 'root.unbind_all("<Tab>")' tab still moves the focus. I commented out the _get_key binding; the tab still moves focus.

Comment: Try `root.unbind_all("<<NextWindow>>")`